# how can call trigger changed event for the html element

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I have the following input box in one html page. When I type the number on this column the value is not being changed without enter or tab key.  The onkeypress has been given common js file for entire html. So I cannot change there . I scare it will affect other working html. Is it possible to call trigger change event in a loop for all input text inside a table 'table' from javascript of that html. So it will make the change event for all the input text under that table

```html
<input type="text" class="borderless-text-sm form-control input-mini" onkeypress="return (event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57) ||event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13|| event.charCode == 9|| event.charCode == 16" min="0" max="24" step="any" autocomplete="off" style="padding-right: 24px;">
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for `onblur`?

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `oninput="return (event.charCode >= 48 &amp;&amp; event.charCode <= 57) ||event.charCode == 46 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13|| event.charCode == 9|| event.charCode == 16"` to the input.

Comment: by its design of the program I cannot change onkeypress to onkeyup.  Becuase that onkeypress given in base js file that will affect the other program also. Is it possible to write the code triggerevent("change") for all the input type="text" under its own html file javascript . I want to call loop for each input text and and call for trigger change